# How to reference the source directory of a `bazel` BUILD file?

Tags: bazel

I have something like the following:

```
sh_binary(
    …
    args = [
        "path/to/this/build/file/relative/to/workspace/root",
    ],
    …
)
```

Is there a way to compute/generate `"path/to/this/build/file/relative/to/workspace/root"` so that if the `BUILD` file is moved, `args` wouldn't have to be changed? Something similar to `$(location)` (I haven't gotten `$(location)` to work since it would introduce a circular dependency)?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `BUILD` file as a data dependency allows you to get its `$(location)`:

```
sh_binary(
    …
    args = ["$(location BUILD.bazel)"],
    data = ["BUILD.bazel"],
    …
)
```